# Calendar resultCode on android

Tags: java, android

There is a similar question on stackoverflow already, but it have not been answered properly so i'll ask again.

I'm creating an event using:

```
Intent intCalendar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intCalendar.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
startActivityForResult(intCalendar, 1);
```

and tried checking if the event was created using

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {
       case 1:
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {}
    }
 }
```

But the thing is, i have to know in the app that i'm developing if the user pressed "SAVE" or "CANCEL" while creating the event. The problem is that calendar doesn't give me a resultCode.

Is there a way that i can check if the user pressed "CANCEL" or "OK" without result code?

Note: I'm new to Android.

Comment: Is onActivityResult getting called? What is the resultCode value in the method? You should receive one.

Comment: Yeah, onActivityResult is getting called, the thing is that resultCode is always 0 when it comes to confirming or cancelling the creation of an event on the native android calendar app.

Answer (score 0):

> i have to know in the app that i'm developing if the user pressed "SAVE" or "CANCEL" while creating the event

Then you will need to work with `CalendarContract`, instead of using `ACTION_EDIT`.

> The problem is that calendar doesn't give me a resultCode.

It is not supposed to give you a result code. [`ACTION_EDIT` has no output](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT).

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware that it's not supposed after reading the documentation, the issue is that i do not know how to implement an alternative that would tell me if the person selected cancel or save like ContactsContracts.Contact gives me.

Comment: @Breno: "i do not know how to implement an alternative that would tell me if the person selected cancel or save" -- there is no alternative, in terms of invoking a calendar app. You would need to write your own UI for editing calendar items. "like ContactsContracts.Contact" -- `ContactsContract.Contact` is not an activity.

Comment: thx for your answer, sry for the confusion on `ContactsContract.Contact`, i didn't mean it was an actual activity, what i was trying to say is that, when working with the contacts native app, when i press cancel i get `resultCode = 0`, and when i pres save i get `resultCode = 1`.

Comment: @Breno: There is no single "contacts native app". There are ~2 billion Android devices. There are ~10,000 device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed "contacts native apps". There could be others that users install from the Play Store or other app distribution channels. Your code can launch any of them. None have to return anything from `ACTION_EDIT`.

Comment: I was not aware it wasn't a native app. Thanks for your help.